# Можно ли так сказать, как написано ниже?

Tags: выбор-слов

«Театр представил моноспектакль по поэзии раннего Маяковского». Один актер читает со сцены стихотворения Маяковского. Можно ли употребить «по поэзии»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вас же не смущает "ранний Маяковский" :) На мой слух, подобное использование слова "поэзия" вполне допустим. Полагаю, "поэзию раннего Маяковского" можно счесть метонимией, заменяющей фразу "ранние поэтические произведения Маяковского".

Comment: Меня смущает «моноспектакль ПО поэзии»...

Comment: Седьмое значение "по" в БТС: *"Употр. при указании на то, что служит основанием или источником действия"*. Не вижу никакой синтаксической разницы между *фильмом по книге* и *спектаклем по поэзии* (с учётом указанной метонимии). Я в школе (или в универе, не помню уже) писал сочинение *по прозе Лермонтова*...

Comment: Не очень звучит, может, потому, что нет конкретики. Что за произведения? Будто по всем ранним сразу. Как и "фильм по творчеству".

Comment: Да, по всем сразу... Спектакль – одно сплошное чтение...

Comment: Может, «посвященный поэзии...»...?

Comment: @oleedd "по" означает "на основе". То есть взято не одно произведение, а использован целый ряд стихов, какие режиссёру потребовались.

Comment: @flossyU нет, смысл меняется. Сравните "фильм по книге" и "фильм, посвящённый книге". Второе — это что-то мемуарное, бэкстейджное.

Comment: По куску сюжета из каждого взяли? Как вырезки из фильмов. Как-то не очень уважительно к поэту.

Comment: @oleedd постмодерн, месьё) Оммажи, пастиши, бриколажи, обыгрывания, режиссёрские взгляды и всё такое прочее. Впрочем, учитывая, что сам Маяковский был новатором, думаю, он был бы не в обиде.

Comment: Придумал: *моноспектакль по ранним произведениям Маяковского*. Так нормально звучит. Абстрактное обобщающее слово не очень подходит в таких случаях.

Comment: Спасибо за окончательный вердикт!:)